# How to delete a file in any of the directories or subdirectories except one subdirectory

Tags: shell

I want to delete a file from a directory which contains many subdirectories but the deletion should not happen in  one subdiretory(searc) whose name is already predefined but path varies as shown below.So now how to delete a file i am using the below command

find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;

this command deletes all the files  in the directory.So How can we  delete the file without serching that subdirectory.

The subdirectory file name will be same but the path will different

for eg

Main
|
a--> searc
|
b-->x--->searc
|
c-->y-->x-->searc
now the 
the subdirectory not to be searched can be present any where as shown above

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `-prune` option.  In combination with a successful name match, this prevents descent into the named directories.  Example:

```
% mkdir -p test/{a,b,c}
% touch test/{a,b,c}/foo.txt
% find test -name b -prune -o -name '*.txt' -print
test/a/foo.txt
test/c/foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you're asking, so I can give only somewhat generic advice.

You already know the `-name` option. This refers to the filename only. You can, however, also use `-wholename` (a.k.a. `-path`), which refers to the full path (beginning with the one given as first option to `find`).

So if you want to delete all `*.txt` files except in the `foo/bar` subdirectory, you can do this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" ! -wholename "./foo/bar/*" -delete
```

Note the `-delete` option; it doesn't require a subshell, and is easier to type.

If you would like to exclude a certain directory name regardless of where in the tree it might be, just don't "root" it. In the above example, `foo/bar` was "rooted" to `./`, so only a top-level `foo/bar` would match. If you write `! -wholename "*/foo/bar/*"` instead (allowing anything before or after via the `*`), you would exclude any files below any directory `foo/bar` from the operation.

Comment: I know the file name to be deleted and the subdirectory for which search should not happen for deletion.But the subdirectory can be in any of the directoies (for ex 10 directories).So now how will i perform deletion of the text file without searching the known sub directory

Comment: @vinod: Still unclear what exactly it is you're after. I expanded the answer a bit.

Answer (score -1):

You can use xargs instead of the exec

```
find .... <without the --exec stuff> | grep -v 'your search' | xargs echo rm -f
```

Try this first. If it is satisfactory, you can remove the echo.

Comment: what does <without exec> do

Comment: What I meant was "do not use the --exec flag in the find command"

Comment: @vinod: This is questionable advice. He's telling you to not use `find`'s `-exec` option, but instead have `find` print the filenames to stdout, which `xargs` turns into command line options again. This requires more system resources (three processes instead of one), and -- since he did not showcase the proper use of `find`'s `-print0` option in combination with `xargs -0` to use zero bytes for termination instead of newlines -- this will **fail** if a path / filename contains whitespaces.

Comment: Yes. If your directory/filenames have space characters or other junk, the echo should reflect it. Trying it with the echo should be safe.

Comment: @DevSolar... I am not attempting to showcase anything. I am just trying to help the OP get what he needs done. I also think that the 3 processes vs. 1 is a non issue.

Comment: @sureshvv: I get that. The problem is that answers will be taken out of context by later visitors looking for a *similar* solution. And those will return here asking "why didn't this work for filenames with spaces" (if they're lucky) or lose files by accident (if they're not). Your solution is fragile, and since you prefer argueing with me instead of fixing it, that's a downvote "not useful" a.k.a. "potentially dangerous".